# Application Share Extension not showing in Share Menu from second time in iOS

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension

I have created application share extension to my app to share photos.For the first time i turned on my app from more.. in share menu.When I ran the app again even though  my app is enabled previously  its not showing in default Share Menu like WhatsApp ,flickr Facebook, i need to on and off my app every time to make it visible.

Do I need to make any changes in the info.plist or in my app to display my app always in share menu ?